# Chat Box on Stack Overflow website

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, chat, stack-exchange

> > **Proposal:** Chat box in the corner of each Stack Exchange website

I believe it would be a good idea to break down the barrier between Stack Exchange chat and its corresponding Stack Exchange website, by allowing users to join a chat room and participate in dialog *while* browsing questions. The dialog chat box would be something similar to the one on Facebook, allowing for the tab to be opened and closed, or exited completely.

> > Possible benefits from such a feature:

- Easier to chat and browse questions at the same time
- Chat in multiple rooms without having to navigate browser tabs and windows
- Possibly improve Stack Exchange answers and response time by discussing questions in chat
  and answering, all in the same window.
- Create a seamless experience between chat and Stack Exchange

Does anyone else see this as a good idea? Chat just seems like such a separate thing from Stack Exchange and it would be nice (in my opinion) to make them more cohesive.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that a *lot* of traffic is anonymous, and you need at least 20 rep to participate in chat. We could show a sort of 'gallery' view of a room, but that's something that anon visitors couldn't really *do* anything with. There's not much sense in showing it to them since it's just something they can't use.

That pretty much whittles it down to showing it only to logged in users that have, or are close to having chat privileges - but those folks are generally quite content to just join the room. I'm not sure what benefit a widget-y box would provide? I don't see how that solves multiple tabs for multiple rooms, and real estate in the side bar is pretty precious :)

Comment: You definitely make some valid points. The main benefit would simply be quick and easy access. I often find it annoying switching back and forth when scrolling through questions and being actively engaged in conversation on chat. Side bar real estate seems to be the biggest issue you pointed out, but if the chat tabs could be maximized and minimized, it would make it pretty easy to get all that content back into view :)